# How to sum the value of child documents in a specific matching search criteria using solr?

Tags: solr, parent-child, solr6, nested-documents

I have the following indexed documents

```
{

    "id":"data1",
    "isParent":"1",
    "_childDocuments":[
        {
            "description":"Benefit and Payroll consultant with HR team ",
            "isParent":"2",
            "exp":2
        },
        {
            "description":" ERP Avalon Implementation and Support Payroll",
            "isParent":"2",
            "exp":5
        }
    ]

}
```

How can I form a query as

**select?q=*:*&fq=(description:Payroll AND sum(exp):7)**

and get the parent **document id  data1** as response.

Please guide me how can  I achive the above query and response with my indexed documents

Comment: Can I achieve this using facets??

Answer (score 0):

I see two options:

1. using [streaming expressions](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/streaming-expressions.html) you should be able to do that
2. if you want to use vanilla solr queries, then add a field at the parent doc level sumExp containing the sum of all children values and then fq on that

Comment: Thank you for your valuable response.I cann't go with second approach because I need to consider the child document wich should have the specified description.Some child documents may not have it.